# How to turn off notifications sounds when OS X is in Do Not Disturb mode? (High Sierra)

Tags: macos, mac, audio, notifications

Toggling "Do Not Disturb" blocks banners/alerts for notifications, but I still hear the sound when I, for example, get a message.

Is there any way to mute the Notification sounds without muting the entire computer?

Comment: I agree, this happen for example with Whatsapp application. Is very annoying

Comment: Same issue here, I came to this question specifically because of WhatsApp.

Answer (score 1):

Notification sounds are silenced in Do Not Disturb mode. Contacts marked with Emergency Bypass will bypass this and allow the notification sound to be played.

Comment: Nope - I agree with the OP.. do not disturb does not silence notification sounds. Very annoying.

Comment: Another vote to confirm OP. Do not disturb allows audio notifications to pass through. Much heart pain.

Comment: This is consuming me! Do not disturb settings say that sounds will be silenced, but I keep hearing Slack, Whatsapp and more.
Please someone come up with a fix!